# Working with external objects through .g4 file in Antlr

Tags: java, antlr

I'm working on an implementation of a database in Java, and need to create an Antlr parser to process query strings like this one:

```
(category(Chinese) || category(Italian)) && price <= 2
```

I have implemented a method `Set<String> category(String regex)` for my database, which returns a set of the names of the restaurants that match the given text, but I have no idea how to call this method from some specific rule in my parser.

I expect that I have to have a parameter in my .g4 file that takes in my Java database object, but using `@parser::members{}` seems like it's only useful for initialising objects.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so sorry if it's not clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give the Set to the parser so that it can then be accessed inside it you can do the following:

```
@parser::members {private Set<String> mySet;
    public MyParser(CharStream input, Set<String> theSet) {
        this(input);
        mySet = theSet;
    }
}
```

You can then access the respective `mySet` inside any parser-action during parsing. However you need to think about using the correct constructor.

You may also need to put the respective `import` statements in `@parser::header`.